# Google Maps Rotate Polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, rotation

After drawing a Polygon shape on the map. I would like to change what direction the polygon is pointing when the map is refreshed by rotating around one of the points of the polygon. For example point the polygon in the direction of 90 degrees rotating around my first polygon point (code shown below).   Can anyone provide any code examples of this working?
I have seen some similar posts however examples given appear over complicated.

```
poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
  strokeWeight: 3,
  fillColor: '#5555FF'
});
poly.setMap(map);
poly.setPaths(new google.maps.MVCArray([path]));

  var triangleCoords = [
  new google.maps.LatLng(51.5087, -0.1277),
  new google.maps.LatLng(51.5387, -0.1077),
  new google.maps.LatLng(51.5387, -0.1477),
  new google.maps.LatLng(51.5087, -0.1277)
];

// Construct the polygon
triangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: triangleCoords,
  strokeColor: "#FF0000",
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: "#FF0000",
  fillOpacity: 0.8
});
triangle.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', triangle);

}
```

Comment: Looks like you have an extra closing "}" at the end of your code, I'll let you remove that (or add the missing open "{" and associated code).  In general rotating a polygon is pretty complicated unless you add some simplifying assumptions. Are you only going to rotate by 90 degree increments?

Answer (score 7):

The following example demonstrates how to rotate a polygon

> Note: the rotation is performed around the first point

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {lat: 24.886, lng: -70.268},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var triangleCoords = [
    {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
    {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
    {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
    {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}
  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
  
  //rotate a polygon
  document.getElementById('btnRotate').onclick = function() {
        rotatePolygon(bermudaTriangle, 90);
  };
}


function rotatePolygon(polygon,angle) {
    var map = polygon.getMap();
    var prj = map.getProjection();
    var origin = prj.fromLatLngToPoint(polygon.getPath().getAt(0)); //rotate around first point

    var coords = polygon.getPath().getArray().map(function(latLng){
       var point = prj.fromLatLngToPoint(latLng);
       var rotatedLatLng =  prj.fromPointToLatLng(rotatePoint(point,origin,angle));
       return {lat: rotatedLatLng.lat(), lng: rotatedLatLng.lng()};
    });
    polygon.setPath(coords);
}

function rotatePoint(point, origin, angle) {
    var angleRad = angle * Math.PI / 180.0;
    return {
        x: Math.cos(angleRad) * (point.x - origin.x) - Math.sin(angleRad) * (point.y - origin.y) + origin.x,
        y: Math.sin(angleRad) * (point.x - origin.x) + Math.cos(angleRad) * (point.y - origin.y) + origin.y
    };
}
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#map {
    height: 100%;
}

#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="floating-panel">
  <input type="button" id="btnRotate" value="Rotate 90"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/70sL1kg6/)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at something like Mike Williams' [eshapes library](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/eshapes.htm).  It was written originally for the Google Maps API v2, but this [page](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_eshapes.html) demonstrates the version that I ported to the Google Maps API v3.

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_eshapes_triangle_rotate.html)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/bp67j9nc/)

**code snippet;**

```js
var map = null;
var triangle, angle, point;

function initMap() {
  point = new google.maps.LatLng(44, -80);

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: point,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    myOptions);

  angle = 0;
  // === Triangle ===
  triangle = google.maps.Polyline.RegularPoly(point, 30000, 3, angle, "#ff0000", 8, 1);
  triangle.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(triangle, "click", rotateTriangle);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

function rotateTriangle() {
  triangle.setMap(null);
  angle += 90;
  if (angle >= 360) angle -= 360;
  triangle = google.maps.Polyline.RegularPoly(point, 30000, 3, angle, "#ff0000", 8, 1);
  triangle.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(triangle, "click", rotateTriangle);
}

// This Javascript is based on code provided by the
// Community Church Javascript Team
// http://www.bisphamchurch.org.uk/   
// http://econym.org.uk/gmap/

// From v3_eshapes.js:
// EShapes.js
//
// Based on an idea, and some lines of code, by "thetoy" 
//
//   This Javascript is provided by Mike Williams
//   Community Church Javascript Team
//   http://www.bisphamchurch.org.uk/   
//   http://econym.org.uk/gmap/
//
//   This work is licenced under a Creative Commons Licence
//   http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/uk/
//
// Version 0.0 04/Apr/2008 Not quite finished yet
// Version 1.0 10/Apr/2008 Initial release
// Version 3.0 12/Oct/2011 Ported to v3 by Lawrence Ross

google.maps.Polyline.RegularPoly = function(point, radius, vertexCount, rotation, colour, weight, opacity, opts) {
  rotation = rotation || 0;
  var tilt = !(vertexCount & 1);
  return google.maps.Polyline.Shape(point, radius, radius, radius, radius, rotation, vertexCount, colour, weight, opacity, opts, tilt)
}
google.maps.Polyline.Shape = function(point, r1, r2, r3, r4, rotation, vertexCount, colour, weight, opacity, opts, tilt) {
  if (!colour) {
    colour = "#0000FF";
  }
  if (!weight) {
    weight = 4;
  }
  if (!opacity) {
    opacity = 0.45;
  }
  var rot = -rotation * Math.PI / 180;
  var points = [];
  var latConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point, new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat() + 0.1, point.lng())) * 10;
  var lngConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point, new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat(), point.lng() + 0.1)) * 10;
  var step = (360 / vertexCount) || 10;

  var flop = -1;
  if (tilt) {
    var I1 = 180 / vertexCount;
  } else {
    var I1 = 0;
  }
  for (var i = I1; i <= 360.001 + I1; i += step) {
    var r1a = flop ? r1 : r3;
    var r2a = flop ? r2 : r4;
    flop = -1 - flop;
    var y = r1a * Math.cos(i * Math.PI / 180);
    var x = r2a * Math.sin(i * Math.PI / 180);
    var lng = (x * Math.cos(rot) - y * Math.sin(rot)) / lngConv;
    var lat = (y * Math.cos(rot) + x * Math.sin(rot)) / latConv;

    points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat() + lat, point.lng() + lng));
  }
  return (new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: points,
    strokeColor: colour,
    strokeWeight: weight,
    strokeOpacity: opacity
  }))
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<b>Click triangle's border to rotate it.</b>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i wanted to rotate a symbol or polygon. The **rotation** attribute defines the rotation of the object and thats all.
Try it.

The **path defines the shape** of the polygon and uses SVG notation like (x,y) coordinates.

```
 function init_nuevo_mapa(){
        var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.5351136,-70.5876618)
        };

        var new_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('new-map'), mapOptions);
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.5351136,-70.5876618)
        var image = {
                         path: 'M 0,0 -10,-30 10,-30 z',
                         rotation: 10, //10º clockwise
                         fillColor: "red",
                         fillOpacity: 0.5,
                         scale: 1,
                         strokeColor: "red",
                         strokeWeight: 4
                     };
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                         position: myLatLng,
                         map: map,
                         icon: image,
                         zIndex: zIndex,
                         title: location[2]
                     });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do it with the new Google Maps symbol object. Just take a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Symbol.

Warning: This works really bad with IE 9 when you have a lot of markers.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for all the response's. Had bit of success using the symbol objects. Problem is the shape is set in pixels so when zooming out the shape becomes larger over the map.  Is it possible to draw shape with lat/long coordinates instead of pixels?   I am hoping the anchor point will position the shape and coordinates will give the correct size relevant to the map. Cheers!

Comment: You can try to change the scale attribute but I realize that Symbol isn't the best solution for your needs. You were right on using polygons. And for rotating them, I think this link will help http://www.kralidis.ca/gis/compcart/polytrans/